# DATE_FORMAT inside a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute this query, but it return an empty cell on months :

```
SELECT 
 year(publication) AS year, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(month(publication), '%M') ORDER BY month(publication) ASC) AS months
 from texts 
 GROUP BY year(publication) ORDER BY year (publication) DESC
```

Whitout DATE_FORMAT, the query works fine. But I need to return months names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
DATE_FORMAT(month(publication), '%M')
```

with

```
DATE_FORMAT(publication, '%M')
```

Answer (score -1):

You also use `GROUP_CONCAT(from_unixtime(timestamp,'%d-%m-%y %H:%i:%s') separator ', ')`